# Задача на построение расписания

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, машинное-обучение

Есть такая задача:
30 работников отметили дни в которые они бы хотели работать ,а в какие отдыхать.

Есть 8 компьютеров за которыми они работают в 2 смены.
Алгоритм должен расставить смены работников на следующий месяц максимально близко к их пожеланиям, так чтобы на выходе получилось готовое расписание.

Я даже примерно не понимаю как это гуглить.
В принципе мне понятно,что алгоритм как то будет обрабатывать веса каждой клетки расписания(грубо говоря), но дальше полнейшее непонимание.
Я уже думал прикрутить сюда что-то типа парцептрона,но скорее всего есть какое то более простое решение(простое с точки зрения кода).

Сложность решения(в математическом плане) в принципе не особо важна, т.к это все будет крутиться на весьма мощном сервере.

Хотелось бы понять в какую сторону вообще копать, в идеале название алгоритма который бы это реализовывал.

UPD.

Рабочий график каждого 2/2,следовательно ситуация в которой человек сидит сутки на работе - нереальна совсем забыл это указать.

Comment: Для начала надо бы формализовать вот это "максимально близко к пожеланиям". Ну а потом можно, например, искать оптимум генетическими алгоритмами.

Comment: @Akina Прошу прощения , поправил пост.

Comment: @Yaant в каком смысле формализовать?
просто может возникнуть проблема , при которой все работники захотят отдохнуть в один день 
я думаю это как то можно решить добавив приоритеты , типа : красный ,зеленый ,желтый 
где красный - максимальное желание отдыхать ,а желтый - безразличие

Comment: В смысле того, чтобы можно было взять два варианта расписания, и однозначно понять, какой из них лучше. Условно говоря, что лучше, сместить одного человека на два дня от желаемого им дня, или двух человек - на один день? Нужна какая-то оценочная функция: на входе - расписание, на выходе - некое число, характеризующее "идеальность" этого расписания.

Comment: @Akina окей , тогда возьмем такие условия :
у нас есть 30 работников и 8 компьютеров.

Comment: *в каком смысле формализовать?* Необходимо составить математическое выражение, которое по заданному графику и заявкам выдало одно число, количественно характеризующее степень соответствия графика и заявок. Например, чем оно меньше, тем соответствие выше. И задача соответственно для пакета заявок составить такой график, для которого это значение наименьшее из всех возможных. Это уже будет обычная задача оптимизации, решаемая стандартными методами (с учётом количества вариантов - вероятно, генетикой).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Исследовании Операций изучаются задачи подобные вашей - Задача о ранце, Задачи составления расписания и др. Смотрите соответствующие материалы, скорее всего точно вашей задачи и не найдете, но среди разновидностей этих задач - а их сотни - удастся найти что-то близкое.

Однако есть сильное предположение, что такие задачи обычно относятся к  задачам, единственным методом решения которых есть полный перебор. В этом случае надо сформулировать критерий по которому вы  будете сравнивать варианты "раскладок работников по рабочим дням". (Простейший вариант  -  сколько пожеланий учтено, а сколько - нет). И тупо перебирать варианты. Тем более задача решается раз в месяц, и потратить на ее решение пару (десятков) часов - в общем-то не проблема.